# installing theme in wordpress at different url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress theme installed at www.abc.com. It is working fine.

I want to install another theme  at the url www.abc.com/sample1.

I have uploaded the other theme to the themes directory, now how to point it to the www.abc.com/sample1 url.

Any ideas pls. It is urgent.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs One WP install can't run two themes at the same time in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up network of blogs on wordpress by reading in codex, all the blogs will use the same database. 
Also you can set up a new database for another instance of wordpress which will be in your sample1 folder. Two independent wordpress instances can run fine on one server wihout any problem.